# Codeigniter Pagination Issue - Undefined property: $pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I have searched here & Google but I don't get the solution for my Issue. 
Below my code for pagination :-

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/books/';
$config['total_rows'] = 20;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 5;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
exit;
```

I'm getting 
   "Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$pagination" 
  and "Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in /var/www/code/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 25".

Can anybody help me what i did wrong. I also tried to initiate the pagination in autoload page. but getting the same error. Looking for experts response.

Comment: Does your Welcome class extend CI_Controller?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of would be if you overrode "load" so that it didn't actually call the base class version.

Comment: Yes, Welcome class extent the CI_Controller. (class Welcome extends CI_Controller)

Comment: And you haven't overridden load in Welcome (or any of it's bases)?

Answer (score 0):

do you have this code in your controller ?

```
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

then pass $data to your view

```
$this->load->view( 'results', $data );
```

then in your view an if check like:

```
<?php if ( strlen($pagination) ) { 

    echo $pagination;

   } else { 

 echo 'No search results' ; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to auto load the pagination library... just loading it in the function will not do.